# VBA for loop only returning one value when there are more that meet the criteria

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, worksheet-function

I am trying to transfer stock transactions from a transaction workbook to another book that has the formatting i want. I want to be able to change the client name and stock at the top of the code so it makes it easier to run for multiple people. the problem is that when i run this it only returns one date in my formatted worksheet when i can see that there are 3 stock trades for the given ticker with different dates in the transaction book. it seems like the FOR function isn't looping through all the rows in the transaction book but im not sure why

```
Sub SortTransactionData()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks("Allen Smith Transactions.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim wb1 As Workbook 
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Allen Smith HI.xlsm")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("MO")

Dim ticker As String
ticker = ws1.Range("A2")

Dim a As Integer
a = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

Dim b As Integer
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws1.Range("B1:B7"), "*")

For i = 2 To a
    'copy date for stock transaction'
    If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = ticker Then
    ws1.Cells(b + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1)
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Some issues i see right from the start is you have `Dim ticker As String` when ticker actually refers to a range, Change `Dim a As Integer` and `Dim b As Integer` to `As Long`, Also run a `Debug.Print ws1.Cells(b+1,2).Value` after the `End If` in your `Loop`; I bet you arent referencing the cell you think you are.

Comment: `b` never changes value so you keep overwriting the same cell as you go through the loop. Add `b = b+1` after `ws1.Cells(b + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1)`

Comment: ok so i changed b and a to as long and changed the ticker to just reflect the stock im looking for "MO" in this case. @cybernetic.nomad i thought i set up b to count the filled cells in the range "B1:B7" i have text in rows one and two so it fills the 3rd row with the date it found but it should recount that range after it finds a date and post the next date found on the 4th row right?

Comment: It doesn'a matter what the value of `b` is, what matters is that ***`b` never changes value***. Cell `ws1.Cells(b + 1, 2)` is always the same cell, so every time you loop you overwrite the old result with the new one. You either need to increment `b` every time (as I suggested) or add the new value to the existing ones (which I don't recommend)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the b = b +1 worked perfectly - so simple too thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the problem is that cell `ws1.Cells(b + 1, 2)` never changes, so you keep overwriting old values as you go through your loop

Change your code to increment the index, `b`, each time through the loop:

```
For i = 2 To a
    'copy date for stock transaction'
    If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = ticker Then
        ws1.Cells(b + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1)
        b = b + 1
    End If
Next i
```